# Pyspark API missing Pandas module _libs.arrays

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

Using apache-spark running on an azure databricks notebook.

```
rdd_s = sc.parallelize(input_dict)
rdd_s = rdd_s.map(lambda day: function(day))
results = pd.concat(rdd_s.collect()) #this line produces the error
```

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 19742.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 19742.0 (TID 80976) (10.5.0.15 executor 42): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: &#39;ModuleNotFoundError: No module named &#39;pandas._libs.arrays&#39;&#39;
```

Completely stuck on this error as I don't know how to view what pandas the api is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas **concat** method is used to concat 2 DataFrames or Series.

```
pandas.concat(objs, axis=0, join='outer', ignore_index=False, keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False, sort=False, copy=True)
```

rdd_s.collect() would return the list as a result,
You are trying to **concat** the list which will not work.

Please check that.

Comment: Hi, I had already tried just doing the collect without the concat but the same error is produced if I just run rdd_s.collect() on that line

Comment: Lists cannot be concatenated. You could just convert the rdd to pandas do using toPandas()